# How do SQLAlchemy / SQL Index compare to Index in pandas?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am learning SQLAlchemy and I am somewhat familiar with pandas. Now, I am trying to understand the concept of indexes in SQLAlchemy and SQL databases in general.

#### In pandas

In pandas, the index is an identifier or "address" for the column<sup>1</sup>. A simple table could look like this:

```
       car_color car_manufacturer engine_type purchase_date
car_id
12           red             Opel          AA    2020-06-05
13           red             Fiat           B    2020-03-14
17         brown            Volvo           A    2020-01-15
27         black             Opel           A    2020-05-01
30          blue             Opel           B    2020-03-24
32         black             Fiat           A    2020-06-04
39         black             Fiat           A    2020-01-07
53         black             Opel           C    2020-04-25
55           red         Maserati           A    2020-07-13
56         white            Volvo           D    2020-03-05
72          blue             Opel           D    2020-02-22
91        silver             Fiat           D    2020-05-28
```

where the `car_id` is the index, and other columns are just, well, columns. I understand that I can sort by the index. I can also select data or modify based on the index. Dataframes have always only one index, but in some cases, there might be a situation where the index is a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html).

#### In SQLAlchemy

In [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/), it is possible to define schema with indices like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, Date, Index

meta = MetaData()
mytable = Table(
    'mytable',
    meta,
    Column('car_id', Integer, index=True),
    Column('car_color', String),
    Column('car_manufacturer', String),
    Column('engine_type', String),
    Column('purchase_date', Date, index=True),
    Index('idx_car_mane', 'car_manufacturer', 'engine_type', unique=True),
)
```

### In SQL

Now, if I check the table creation script with

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:mypass@127.0.0.1:5432/testdatabase', echo=True)
mytable.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

it looks like this<sup>2</sup>

```
2020-07-29 01:36:26,590 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine select relname from pg_class c join pg_namespace n on n.oid=c.relnamespace where pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid) and relname=%(name)s
2020-07-29 01:36:26,607 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'name': 'mytable'}
2020-07-29 01:36:26,618 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE mytable (
        car_id INTEGER,
        car_color VARCHAR,
        car_manufacturer VARCHAR,
        engine_type VARCHAR,
        purchase_date DATE
)


2020-07-29 01:36:26,691 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_car_mane ON mytable (car_manufacturer, engine_type)
2020-07-29 01:36:26,719 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine CREATE INDEX ix_mytable_purchase_date ON mytable (purchase_date)
2020-07-29 01:36:26,761 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine CREATE INDEX ix_mytable_car_id ON mytable (car_id)
```

Then, I add three rows manually by

```py
engine.execute(mytable.insert(), car_id=12, car_color='red', car_manufacturer='Opel', engine_type='AA', purchase_date=dt.date(2020, 6, 5))
engine.execute(mytable.insert(), car_id=13, car_color='red', car_manufacturer='Fiat', engine_type='B', purchase_date=dt.date(2020, 3, 14))
engine.execute(mytable.insert(), car_id=17, car_color='brown',car_manufacturer='Volvo',  engine_type='A',  purchase_date=dt.date(2020, 1, 15))
```

and look at the database using pgAdmin:

[image: pgAdmin view]

I can see that the 5 columns are there as assumed, but the Indexes are not drawn to the same table as the columns, but they are listed separately under "Indexes".

### Question

Is the concept of indices in SQLAlchemy/SQL in general similar to what it is in pandas, and if not, what are the differences?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Although it is also possible to define duplicate indices.  <sup>2</sup>  Removed some rows for clarity.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The indexes in Pandas is associated with the rows. However in SQLAlchemy is associated with the concept of indexes in the relational database.

A index (in databases) is a data structure (or a tool uf you want to see like it) that imporves the speed of data retrieval. (See [database index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index))